# How to show previous domain with javascript document.referrer

Tags: javascript

I want to show the domain that user came from to my page with `document.referrer`. But I dont want to show all name of this site for example: www.mysite.pl/page2314 but only the domain - www.mysite.pl

How to do that?

Comment: Yes I forgot to add my tryings, sorry

Comment: @user1743942: For your information, it is possible to edit your questions and add such information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can among other things use a regular expression like this:

```
var referrer = document.referrer
var doman = referrer.match(/:\/\/([^/]+)\//)[1]
```

This will match anything in an url after `://` up to (but not including) the following `/`.

If `document.referrer` is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions`, the matched domain will be `stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what to do with `www.` I want to remove it when someone comes from www.mypage.pl/xxxx

Comment: @Glutamat: What does `?:` do in `(?:www\.)?`?

Comment: The `?:` hides a capture group

Comment: Now i got the right Term, it makes it a "non-capturing" group

Comment: If you want to have it explained in detail:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group

Answer (score 0):

What about a regex which only matchs the first part ? like

Edited: thx @David

`document.referrer.match(/((ht{1}(tp|tps):\/\/)[\w\d\S]+?)\//g)[0] //"http://stackoverflow.com/"`

Of course you can use any suitable regex

Comment: What if the referrer starts with `https`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ref = document.referrer;
ref = ref.substring(ref.indexOf("://") + 3)
ref = ref.split("/")[0];
```

Now ref only contains the domain. A different approach would be with regex.

Comment: Not all domain names start with `www`.

Comment: yeah, i thought of it after. i was thinking of the given example. i'll make the correction.